# pass an array with unknown objects into string.Format in c#

Tags: c#

I would like to output all objects in an array of strings for which the length is variable.

```
example 1 :
string id = A;
string [] values = new string [] {"12","23"};
string output = string.Format("{0}, {1}, id, values);
//output should be "A,12,23"

example 2 :
string id = A;
string [] values = new string [] {"12","23","45","67","89"};
string output = string.Format("{0}, {1}, id, values);
//output should be "A,12,23,45,67,89"
```

Is there any way which would cover any number of values or do I need to convert the values into a String and then output it?

Comment: There are some overloads of `string.Join` that you can try... They are present in C# >= 4.0 and they work with arrays and `IEnumerable<>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it easily with a `string.Join(string, string[])`

```
string.Join(",", values)
```

it will add the separator char and will output it in the way you want it

An overview of the methods you could use for it are here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx